# Python ERROR: Could not build wheels for cx_Oracle, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm trying to install cx_Oracle and I get this error,
I have the latest setuptools and pip installed.
Has anyone had a similar problem and how did they solve it?

I have Visual Studio: please see image

[image: Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Versions listed]

```
Processing c:\....resources\cx_oracle-8.1.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cx_Oracle
  Building wheel for cx_Oracle (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for cx_Oracle (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  ¦ exit code: 1
  ?-> [7 lines of output]
      C:\....\2\pip-build-env-806_5jc6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\expand.py:144: UserWarning: File 'C:\\....\\2\\pip-install-r8jb3ohi\\cx-oracle_111cfa7e3d91425bb65e9a6baa89c82f\\README.md' cannot be found
        warnings.warn(f"File {path!r} cannot be found")
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'cx_Oracle' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cx_Oracle
Failed to build cx_Oracle
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cx_Oracle, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: I don't know what you are actually going to do with cx_Oracle, but check this: 
https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/

Answer (score 6):

The image you showed has *redistributables*, not Visual Studio itself! You will need to follow the provided link to get the Microsoft build tools installed if you want to build it yourself.

If you use pip, however, you should be able to download and install prebuilt binaries -- which is a LOT easier! The command to use is:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle
```

EDIT: cx_Oracle has been superseded by python-oracledb. Install that via this command:

```
python -m pip install oracledb
```

Comment: I have 1) VS Build tools installed (v17+) and 2) I used your command -- I still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can install Anaconda for your OS, and run the following command to install `cx_oracle`. Anaconda takes care of the entire build process (wheel issue).

`conda install -c anaconda cx_oracle`

cx_Oracle was already integrated into my project (alongside everyone on the team). I couldn't switch to oracledb. If you're starting a new project kindly `pip install oracledb`

Answer (score 0):

mayBe beacause the version of python,when I use 3.10.9 is ok,but 3.11.0 not

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This the version. Request Python 3.10.9 for cx_Oracle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).